# nav-item dropdown in NavBar,Is there any way to make it show borders when using btn-outline on it?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4, navbar

I can use outline styled buttons on common Navbar nav-item, but when it's a "nav-item dropdown" the button is not showing its borders, see on the image below. Is there any way to make it show borders?

[image]

```
<!-- Dropdown -->
<li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle btn-outline-secondary" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Disprofarma
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/PedidoDisprofarma/Index">Pedidos</a>
        <a class="dropdown-item" href="/RecepcionDisprofarma/Index">Recepción de Pedidos</a>
    </div>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure, why you are using `nav-item` here, but if you want to use `btn-outline-secondary` class, then you need to add `btn` class too, [see here](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/buttons/)

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

  <!-- Dropdown -->
  <li class="nav-item dropdown">
    <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle btn btn-outline-secondary" href="#" id="navbardrop" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button">
        Disprofarma
    </a>
    <div class="dropdown-menu">
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/PedidoDisprofarma/Index">Pedidos</a>
      <a class="dropdown-item" href="/RecepcionDisprofarma/Index">Recepción de Pedidos</a>
    </div>
  </li>
</body>
```